# Port 22 Connection Refused when trying to ssh between two AWS instances using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

```
 TASK [SSH connection between the ansible server and the new server] *************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
{"changed": true, "cmd": "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -vvv -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/my.key ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx \"cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\"",
"delta": "0:00:03.052818", "end": "2021-10-04 05:57:48.631244", "msg": "non-zero return code", 
"rc": 255, "start": "2021-10-04 05:57:45.578426", "stderr": "OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  
31 Mar 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: 
Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname  
xx.xx.xxx.xx   is address\r\ndebug2: 
ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebug1: Connecting to  xx.xx.xxx.xx [ xx.xx.xxx.xx ] port 22.\r\ndebug1: 
connect to address  xx.xx.xxx.xx   port 22: Connection refused\r\nssh: connect to host  xx.xx.xxx.xx   
port 22: Connection refused", 
"stderr_lines": ["OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020", "debug1: 
Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config", "debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config", 
"debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname  xx.xx.xxx.xx   is address","debug2: ssh_connect_direct", 
"debug1: Connecting to  
xx.xx.xxx.xx [ xx.xx.xxx.xx  ] port 22.", "debug1: connect to address  xx.xx.xxx.xx   port 22: Connection refused", "ssh: connect to host  xx.xx.xxx.xx   port 22: Connection refused"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
    

Here  "xx.xx.xxx.xx" means my newly created server's public ip.
```

I'm trying to copy the public key from ansible-server to a newly created server using ansible, which is working manually, but the automation through ansible is creating this issue and blocking me to perform the other tasks which are in the playbook.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Can you log into it without using Ansible, i.e., using only SSH?

Comment: Yes @MarkoE , I can ssh into the other server when I copy the public key manually with the same command -
"cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -vvv -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/my.key ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys""

But when I automate that through ansible like this:

 - name: SSH connection between the ansible server and the new server
     shell: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/my.key ubuntu@{{ instance_eip.public_ip }} "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

This is failing and says connection refused.

Comment: First, does `ansible -k -m ping` work?  (It should prompt for the password.)  If that works, use the `copy` module.  If the file `.ssh/authorized_keys` already exists, use the `lineinfile` module to add the key.  You should post the play in your question, but from the above comment, it looks like you need `delegate_to: localhost` on that `shell` task.